# how can I get frame position after autoresizing?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autoresize, custom-cell

I have a `imageView` and i want get x,y,width and height from it after `imageView` autoresizing. Every time is returning original frame.
My `imageView` is in a **custom cell** for `tableView` and these lines don't working.

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    GameCell *cell=[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"gameCell"];

    frameImg1=cell.image1.frame;
    frameImg2=cell.image1.bounds;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use `-(void)viewDidAppear` to get frame size after autoresizing.

Comment: -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    GameCell *cell=[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"gameCell"];
    
    frameImg1=cell.image1.frame;
    frameImg2=cell.image1.bounds;
}

Comment: Is returning :
frameImg1 CGRect origin=(x=55, y=9) size=(width=28, height=28) 
frameImg2 CGRect origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=28, height=28)

Comment: Yes , its correct. Bounds always {x-0,y-0} respect .

Comment: And, my question? How can  get  frame after autoresizing?